# Detecting faulty geometry WKT and returning the faulty record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Folks,
I suspect this is easy but I'm struggling to find a good reference.

I have a table containing a WKT column of lines, points and polygons. I'm processing the WKT into a geography column.

For the most part that's working however I'd like to QA the WKT before processing.

I'm running into trouble here.

The simplest thing I tried was

```
select *  
from GEOMWKT 
where geometry::STGeomFromText(GEOG_WKT, 4326).STIsValid() = 0;
```

However this breaks when there's a genuinely faulty record.

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24117: The LineString input is not valid because it does not have enough distinct points. A LineString must have at least two distinct points.
```

To try and mitigate this I tried the following

```
-- Verify that the stored procedure does not already exist.
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'usp_GetErrorInfo', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo;
GO

-- Create procedure to retrieve error information.
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo
AS
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
GO

BEGIN TRY
   select * from GEOMWKT where geometry::STGeomFromText(GEOG_WKT, 4326).STIsValid() = 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
END CATCH;
```

While this returns what it can, the error is managed and returned but I still don't know which record it is.

How can I return the ID column or something of the record that's failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to my question using cursors. As I've read we don't like cursors as a rule but this works.

I would prefer the elegance of an Stored Procedure or Function but this gets it done.

Please note: per the original link this uses two approaches to finding invalid geometries. Sometimes you get a duplicate ID sometimes not depending on the failure.

I'm still interested in improvements as I'd like to set up a Stored Procedure to report these things before we do processing on them.

```
    -- ---------------------------------------------------- 
--   Find invalid geometry in given Spatial table 
-- ---------------------------------------------------- 

DECLARE @id INT, @n INT, @g varchar(max);

-- create error log table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ERR_CorruptedGeom]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[ERR_CorruptedGeom];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ERR_CorruptedGeom](
    recordid [int] NULL,
    table_name Varchar(25) NULL,
    errtext Varchar(MAX) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

-- define QA cursor on spatial table
DECLARE qa_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT GEOMID, GEOG_WKT
    FROM dbo.GEOMWKT;

OPEN qa_cursor -- open cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM qa_cursor INTO @id, @g;

-- run over table records from the begining to the end 
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) 
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

  -- conventional way to find invalid geometry 
  IF geometry::STGeomFromText(@g, 4326).STIsValid()=0 
  BEGIN 
    -- insert problematic record number into Log table 
   INSERT INTO dbo.ERR_CorruptedGeom (recordid, table_name, errtext) 
   VALUES (@id, 'dbo.GEOMWKT', 'Invalid Geometry');
  END

  -- trying to read invalid geometry will raise Error 
  SET @n = geometry::STGeomFromText(@g, 4326).STNumGeometries();

END TRY

-- error catch block
BEGIN CATCH

  -- insert problematic record reference to Log table 
  INSERT INTO dbo.ERR_CorruptedGeom (recordid, table_name, errtext)
  VALUES (@id, 'dbo.GEOMWKT', ERROR_MESSAGE());

END CATCH;

FETCH NEXT FROM qa_cursor INTO @id, @g;

END

-- close cursor 
CLOSE qa_cursor;
DEALLOCATE qa_cursor;


-- see results 
select * from ERR_CorruptedGeom
```

This is from here http://www.sqlexamples.info/SPAT/mssql_invalid_geometry.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a store procedure to convert txt to geometry, also you dont need cast to geometry, that function already return a geometry object.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetGeometry
    (@Geomtxt  varchar(500) )
AS
DECLARE @ReturnValue as geometry

BEGIN TRY
   select @ReturnValue = STGeomFromText(@Geomtxt , 4326);
   RETURN @ReturnValue
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     RETURN NULL
END CATCH; 
GO
```

then use the function to each row.

```
select *, usp_GetGeometry( GEOG_WKT )
from GEOMWKT
```

Comment: As copied the SP code doesn't execute.
`'STGeomFromText' is not a recognized built-in function name.`
If I add `geometry::` to STGeomfromText the error changes to
`Operand type clash: geometry is incompatible with int` on line `RETURN @Returnvalue` but I like where this is going.

Comment: I do lot of this in postgreSql and postgis, will have to do some research if you need do `variable::geometry` or `geometry::variable`, also check if you have it installed properly.

Comment: Instead of a stored procedure, you could create a user defined function that returns a geometry value.

Comment: @BenThul You are right. Was my fault I use more Postgres and there function and storeprocedures are the same. But SqlServer has functions.

Comment: Ah yes but SQL UDFs don't support TRY..CATCH blocks which is actually the main issue. Just using the spatial functions to detect the faulty WKT cause exceptions that need a CATCH block to respond. However I'm sure mixed in here is something that will work.