# MySQL save Polygon, geometry data type

Tags: python, mysql, gis, geopandas

I have polygon geometries data in MySQL table. The data is stored as text and I need to save the data as `geometry` datatype.

```
state_fips_code tract_ce    tract_geom
6               576700      POLYGON((-118.169788 33.74847, -118.167625 33.747597, -118.165187 33.747139, -118.165741 33.739433, -118.162769 33.739184, -118.162638 33.73965, -118.162508 33.740117, -118.161791 33.742436, -118.161766 33.742512, -118.160742 33.746281, -118.160714 33.746387, -118.159262 33.751741, -118.158781 33.753463, -118.157518 33.757987, -118.156954 33.760101, -118.156884 33.760362, -118.156531 33.761425, -118.15616 33.76175, -118.155959 33.762416, -118.15577 33.763042, -118.155603 33.763596, -118.155444 33.764124, -118.155268 33.764727, -118.154575 33.764584, -118.154574 33.765026, -118.15458 33.766035, -118.154581 33.766266, -118.154584 33.767057, -118.154589 33.767951, -118.15459 33.768073, -118.155696 33.768074, -118.155904 33.768074, -118.156762 33.768076, -118.157844 33.768077, -118.158646 33.768078, -118.158925 33.768079, -118.159534 33.76808, -118.159557 33.76808, -118.160268 33.76808, -118.160584 33.768081, -118.161666 33.768076, -118.161683 33.768076, -118.162772 33.768078, -118.162938 33.768078, -118.163854 33.768079, -118.16421 33.76808, -118.164738 33.768074, -118.165013 33.768097, -118.165136 33.768129, -118.165204 33.768161, -118.165299 33.768232, -118.165379 33.768324, -118.165389 33.768291, -118.165424 33.768173, -118.165457 33.768062, -118.165463 33.768042, -118.165621 33.767529, -118.16568 33.767337, -118.165806 33.766926, -118.16599 33.766328, -118.166149 33.765794, -118.166308 33.76528, -118.166632 33.764199, -118.166191 33.764109, -118.166348 33.763579, -118.16643 33.763468, -118.166608 33.762587, -118.166728 33.761999, -118.16676 33.761851, -118.166769 33.761802, -118.166792 33.761705, -118.16816 33.755431, -118.168649 33.753374, -118.169788 33.74847))
```

In pandas, I do:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
from shapely import wkt

df['geometry'] = df['tract_geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
df_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
```

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE geom MODIFY tract_geom Polygon;
```

I get:

```
Error Code: 1416. Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

How do I update `mysql` table and the datatype of the column to `geometry`?

Comment: A guess:  Add a `POLYGON`; `UPDATE` to set the conversion of `tract_geom` through text or MKB to a `POLYGON`; then drop the old column.

Comment: are you looking for [`ST_GeomFromTxt`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ST_GeomFromTxt`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext) to convert a WKT string geometry column to a Geometry column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE geom
ADD COLUMN geometry Polygon;

# insert column into table
UPDATE geom
SET geometry = (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromTxt(prev.tract_geom)
    FROM geom as prev
    WHERE prev.tract_ce = geom.tract_ce
)
```

This is definitely more easily done by creating a new table and inserting all rows with something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO geom_polygons
(
    SELECT 
      geom.state_fips_code as state_fips_code,
      geom.tract_ce as tract_ce,
      ST_GeomFromTxt(geom.tract_geom) as tract_geom
    FROM geom
)
```

Comment: I get an error `Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext.` when attempting to `INSERT` into table.

Comment: if you have invalid geometries in your data that's a separate question - check out this post for guidance on wrapping the WKT conversion in a try/catch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616177/detecting-faulty-geometry-wkt-and-returning-the-faulty-record

Comment: I am not too familiar with stored procedures or advanced sql. I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451058/geopandas-mysql-gis-data-invalid-geometries

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column first of type POLYGON and then set values of that column using ST_PolygonFromText from your text column

```
ALTER TABLE GEOM ADD tract_geom_poly POLYGON;


UPDATE GEOM SET tract_geom_poly = ST_PolygonFromText(tract_geom) WHERE tract_geom!='' AND tract_geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I tried this approach, however, I am getting `Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.` error.

Comment: I ran it on the example data that you have provided in your question. It works for that. Probably you have invalid geometries in data.

Comment: yeah, it's a large dataset. So, there are likely invalid geometries. I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451058/geopandas-mysql-gis-data-invalid-geometries