# GeoPandas + MySQL - GIS data / Invalid Geometries

Tags: mysql, geometry, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I have a `geopandas` DataFrame that I insert into a MySQL database. When I attempt to set `geometry` in MySQL table, I am running into an error. I check for valid geometries in python and then insert into SQL. Here's my code and sample data:

Sample geo-data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/14ni2mfppt5dn7x/gdf%20%281%29.csv?dl=0

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon 
from shapely import wkt

# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user'
pwd = 'pwd'
host =  'host1'
port = 3306
database = 'db'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))

gdf = gpd.read_file()

# To GeoPandas
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['zip_code_geom'].apply(wkt.loads)

# Fix Bad Geometries
def valid_geom(geom):
    try:
       return wkt.loads(geom)
    except:
       return np.nan


gdf['geometry'] = gdf.zip_code_geom.apply(valid_geom)

# Set Geometry
gdf = gdf.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry='geometry')

# MultiPolygon to Polygon
gdf = gdf.explode(column='geometry', ignore_index=True, index_parts=False)

# Insert into SQL
con = engine.connect()
gdf.to_sql(name="gdf_sql", con=con, if_exists = 'replace')
con.close()
```

Now, the `geometry` column is stored as `text` in MySQL and we need to convert it to `Polygon`.

I attempted the following, but keep getting `Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.`

```
UPDATE db1.gdf_sql SET geometry = ST_PolygonFromText(geometry) WHERE geometry!='' AND geometry IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE db1.gdf_sql
ADD COLUMN geom_poly Polygon;

# insert column into table
UPDATE db1.gdf_sql 
SET geometry = (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromTxt(t1.geometry)
    FROM geom as t1
    WHERE t1.geometry = db1.gdf_sql.geometry
)
```

I need to save the `geometries` in mysql to be able to perform spatial functions in my queries.

Answer (score 3):

For one - `nan` isn’t a valid geometry. So you can either drop NaNs before sending to sql or handle them in a way that will be parsed by `ST_GeomFromTxt` correctly. For this, you can use an empty `GeometryCollection`, e.g. `shapely.geometry.GeometryCollection()`.

Second - when converting to any string format geopandas runs [`to_wkt`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_wkt.html) under the hood. This in turn calls [`pygeos.to_wkt`](https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#pygeos.io.to_wkt), and all keyword arguments (and defaults) are passed to (inherited from) the others function. By default, the precision of geometries is reduced to 6 decimal places prior to sending to wkt (and then sql) and this can cause valid shapes to become invalid, especially when you're talking about geospatial data in degrees. Excerpted from the [pygeos docs](https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#pygeos.io.to_wkt):

> **`to_wkt`** *`(geometry, rounding_precision=6, trim=True, output_dimension=3, old_3d=False, **kwargs)`*
>
> Converts to the Well-Known Text (WKT) representation of a Geometry.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **`rounding_precision`** *`int`, default 6*
>
>   The rounding precision when writing the WKT string. Set to a value of -1 to indicate the full precision.

To get around this, you can do the conversion yourself prior to sending to sql:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf).assign(
    geometry=gdf.geometry.to_wkt(rounding_precision=-1),
)
```

Finally, there is a concept of "valid geometries" which is different from "parseable by wkt.loads", so your test may not be working as intended. While [it is possible to define polygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons) with collinear interior rings and other "invalid" shapes in shapely, spatial operations will not work (or may not work as intended) depending on the language and operation. I'm not sure how MySQL's geometry engine deals with this - they may just throw an error, so this is another place where errors could be creeping in. You can check for valid shapes with [`gdf.geometry.is_valid.all()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.is_valid.html), or find invalid ones with `gdf[~gd.geometry.is_valid]`.

Comment: 1) I didn't have any `nan` in the data with invalid geometries. 2) I did the conversion of geometry to `to_wkt` with full precision. 3) `gdf.geometry.is_valid.all()` returns `True`.  After running the `sql insert` statement and attempting to `update` `geometry` column to `Polygon` type, I still get `Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.` error.

Comment: any other ideas ? Would prefer to fix any invalid geometries in python before sending to sql. Most of the valid geometry tests haven't been able to fix them.

Comment: Sorry - this and the try/catch sql syntax are all the tricks I have. Good luck!

Comment: I am not too familiar with using `try/catch` or `stored procedures` in mysql. Can you suggest a solution if you're familiar with using them in mysql?

Comment: I’be never done this in MySQL - I’ve only ever done this in google bigquery. But the answer I sent you has code that loops through the geometries and tests for validity. It seems like that’s a good approach. But I can’t help you more than that :/ sorry

Comment: The issue seems to be the axis-order of the geometries. I have them in `long-lat` format, however, geographics SRSs in MySQL require them to be `lat-long`. https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/axis-order-in-spatial-reference-systems/

Comment: WOOAAAAAAAHHH. That's crazy. Nice digging! Yeah it seems like you need to do `ST_GeomFromText(t1.geometry, 4326, 'axis-order=long-lat')`?

Comment: Actually, I used `shapely.ops.transform` to change the axis-order to `lat-long` and then send to MySQL. However, when I run the update statement to change geometry column type to `Polygon`, I still run into the error.