# MySQL - Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial

I have a table in mysql with geometry data in one of the columns. The datatype is `text` and I need to save it as Polygon geometry.

I have tried a few solutions, but keep running into `Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.` error.

Here's some data to work with and an example:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78ac63e16ccb5b1e4012c21809cba5ff

Table has `25k` rows, there are likely some bad geometries in there. When I attempt to update on a subset of rows, it seems to successfully work, like it did in the fiddle example. It fails when I attempt to update all `25k` rows.

Someone suggested using wrapping the statements around `TRY` and `CATCH`. [Detecting faulty geometry WKT and returning the faulty record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616177/detecting-faulty-geometry-wkt-and-returning-the-faulty-record)

I am not too familiar with using them in MySQL or stored procedures either.

I need a spatial index on the table to be able to use spatial functions and filter queries by location.

Comment: Incorrect input file. Check your file, row=56 (index=54).

Comment: Near Mt. Taylor?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Create a new table and try to convert as you `INSERT IGNORE INTO` that table from your existing table.  I don't know if this will apply the "IGNORE" to conversion failures.  Also, you would end up with the "good" values.  What do you want to do about the "bad" values?

Plan B:  Write a loop in application code -- read one row, convert the varchar value, check for errors.

Comment: Yeah, I am creating a new table and then inserting the data. I'd like to inspect the bad values, check how many there are and then proceed from there. I created a new post w/ details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494111/error-with-pymysql-pymysql-err-operationalerror-1241-operand-should-conta

Comment: @kms - A `LEFT JOIN` can be used to discover the rows in one table that are not in the other.

Comment: I tried the INSERT with IGNORE, it didn't make a difference. I get `Operand should contain 1 column(s) error`